# iPhone custom label in contacts

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts

I am having trouble saving a contact with a custom label in iOS4. I received a phone call from a number not stored in my phone. After the call, I clicked the blue chevron next to the number >> Create New Contact >> Entered name info >> click "mobile" >> Add Custom Label >> Entered my label name >> Save

At this point, the phone number shows up correctly, with the custom tag. When I press Done, it goes back to the "mobile" tag.

I was able to do this in 3.x. Is this an iOS4 bug?

Comment: my iphone 4 ( only one week old, with iOS 4.3 installed 5 days ago), HAD custom labels but now doesnt.  Did it go away between 4.2 and 4.3   ???

Comment: Do you sync your contacts with google? If so, than you can't sync custom labels.

Comment: Nope I didn't sync contacts with Google. But this was 3 iPhones ago lol. It's not an issue anymore. Thanks for the reply though!

Answer (score 1):

I did this when editing a contact a few days ago. So the functionality is there.

Comment: Ditto, I was able to do the same in iOS4 on an iPhone4.

Comment: Thanks for the info guys. Mine still won't work though. I filed a bug report. Strange.